# Azure Neural Voice: Invalid deploymentId

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I trained, created and deployed a Custom Voice model with Azure's Speech Studio.

On the Deploy Model page, I am given a Resource key, a Service region and Endpoint ID. I used the Endpoint ID (I am sure it is correct) in my code below.

However, I'm getting this error:
**Error code: 1007. Error details: Invalid deploymentId XXXXX USP state: TurnStarted. Received audio size: 0 bytes.]
CANCELED: Did you set the speech resource key and region values?**

Can anyone give a hint as to why it isn't working?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

class Program 
{
    // This example requires environment variables named "SPEECH_KEY" and "SPEECH_REGION"
    static string speechKey = "my-resource-key";
    static string speechRegion = "my-region";

    

    static void OutputSpeechSynthesisResult(SpeechSynthesisResult speechSynthesisResult, string text)
    {
        switch (speechSynthesisResult.Reason)
        {
            case ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
                Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized for text");
                break;
            case ResultReason.Canceled:
                var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(speechSynthesisResult);
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

                if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you set the speech resource key and region values?");
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion);  
           

        // The language of the voice that speaks.
        speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "MyNeuralVoice"; 
        speechConfig.EndpointId = "my-endpoint-id"; 

        using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig))
        {
            // Get text from the console and synthesize to the default speaker.
            Console.WriteLine("Enter some text that you want to speak >");
            string text = Console.ReadLine();

            var speechSynthesisResult = await speechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
            OutputSpeechSynthesisResult(speechSynthesisResult, text);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not saying it is necessarily related, but they seem to have closed a very similar issue (about Recognizer not showing this exact message) last week: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/2220. Usually I wouldn't jump to "its the sdk, not my code!" but I wouldn't be surprised if unifying exeption handling changed something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I tried your code from my end and successfully converted the text to speech.*

**Note :**

1. Whenever making a request, ensure the status is **Succeeded**. If it is **Processing** or **Suspended**, you will receive an error.

[image]

2. If I provided the incorrect **deploymentID**, I also received the same error as shown below:

[image]

Follow the steps below to create a **Text to Speech Custom Neural Voice**:

1. Go to the [Speech Studio (microsoft.com)](https://speech.microsoft.com/portal) and click on create **Custom Voice** as below:

[image]

2. Click on **Create a project**. I already have a project named **kamtts** as below:

[image]

3. Go to **Record and build**. Record some samples (I recorded 32 samples) and click on **Train model** as below:

[image]

4. Go to **Review model** and check the details in your model as below:

[image]

5. Go to **Deploy model** > click on **Deploy model** to deploy your model as below:

[image]

6. Go to your deployment model > Copy the **Endpoint key**, **region**, and **deploymentId** as below:

[image]
[image]

Use the above **Endpoint key**, **region**, and **deploymentId** in the code below.

**Code :**

```cs
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

class Program
{
    static string speechKey = "<speech_key>";
    static string speechRegion = "<speech_region>";

    static void OutputSpeechSynthesisResult(SpeechSynthesisResult speechSynthesisResult, string text)
    {
        switch (speechSynthesisResult.Reason)
        {
            case ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted:
                Console.WriteLine($"Speech synthesized for text");
                break;
            case ResultReason.Canceled:
                var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(speechSynthesisResult);
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

                if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails=[{cancellation.ErrorDetails}]");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you set the speech resource key and region values?");
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    async static Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion);
        speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US"; //Replace your voice name here, I used en-US 
        speechConfig.EndpointId = "<deploymentID>";

        using (var speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter some text that you want to speak >");
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            var speechSynthesisResult = await speechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text);
            OutputSpeechSynthesisResult(speechSynthesisResult, text);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**Output :**

The code ran successfully, and I received the following prompt to enter some text input to obtain speech output:

[image]

I entered the text **Hi Kamali. How are you?** and heard the speech output for the provided input text, resulting in this message:

[image]

```
Enter some text that you want to speak >
Hi Kamali. How are you?
Speech synthesized for text
Press any key to exit...
```

**Reference :**

Check this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=windows,terminal&pivots=programming-language-csharp) to convert **text to speech**.

Comment: Yes thank you, I figured out you must use CUSTOM VOICE not "Custom Speech" for Neural voice! It works for me now.